# Can't connect to Ec2 instance: "Connection refused on port 22"

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have been able to successfully log into my ec2 2 times in the past. Now when I try to login, I get this error

```
ssh -vvv -i "test.ppk" oracle@ec2-11-162-345-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-11-162-345-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com [56.187.068.298] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 56.187.068.298 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-11-162-345-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

After doing some research, i believe this is because the first time i logged into the instance, I was at home. The second time, I was at someone else house. So maybe my ip address is now blocked from entering. I'm using a default security group that allows all connections so idk where to go from here.

Comment: IIRC the default firewall settings *disallow* all incoming(!) connections.

Comment: @DanielB But I was able to connect to it before and I didn't change any settings. And I just checked the inbound settings now and it is set to allow all connections

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ssh/2926/debugging-ssh-problems/18370/connection-refused#t=201706061806070892013